# Mysterious conversion?

Tags: c++, linked-list

Okay so I am trying to understand the internals of a LinkedList and I have made two classes, Node and LinkedList. For some reason, the node constructor is spitting out an int rather than a node.

```
Node* head; // throws " error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'Node*' [-fpermissive]"
int whyDoesThisWork = new Node(); //by god this works
```

The first case was annoying, but the second is actually kind of funny.
Here is my Node.h:

```
#ifndef NODE_H_
#define NODE_H_

class Node {
public:
    Node();
    Node(int val);
    ~Node();
    int value;
    Node* next;
};

#endif /* NODE_H_ */
```

My Node.cpp:

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
Node::Node() {
    this->value = 0;
    this->next = NULL;

}
Node::Node(int val) {
    this->value = val;
    this->next = NULL;
}
```

I am absolutely clueless to why a Node constructor is returning an int. Any insight would be appreciated

Edit
Here is my driver file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
  Node* head;
  int* val = new Node();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Where are those first 2 lines being used for example?

Comment: The shown code in this question does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @RemyLebeau My compiler was previously throwing an error about Node returning an int. All of a sudden, it is working and the errors are reversed meaning everything works as it should. I did not edit my source or header. Does GCC cache files for easy compilation? I have had a few situations where GCC spits strange errors out but a fresh rebuild fixes everything (despite having previously been saved earlier). I am not stupid, would a 5 year old computer be prone to having more errors per operation, allowing for this? Or do you think it was GCC?

Comment: @ErikAwwad "*My compiler was previously throwing an error about Node returning an int*" - no compiler would ever return an `int` from a `new` expression. I think you were misreading what the compiler was actually saying.

Comment: @RemyLebeau error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'Node*' [-fpermissive] is pretty clear. I apologize for being rude. It is hard to tell if you are being condescending right now.

Comment: "invalid conversion from 'int' to 'Node*" is certainly pretty clear. Something is attempting to convert an `int` to a `Node *`. What is not clear is that this is, allegedly, happening in an otherwise well-formed `new` expression. Nowhere is that referenced in this cited error message.

Comment: What's the line *before* the one that shows the error?

Comment: @ErikAwwad There is no possible way that `int whyDoesThisWork = new Node();` can convert FROM `int` TO `Node*`, because 1) `new` does not return `int`; and 2) `whyDoesThisWork` is not a `Node*`. Same with `int* val = new Node();`. So, the error message is either 1) completely bogus; or 2) referring to a different line of code. The ONLY way I could see a conversion FROM `int` TO `Node*` is if you were doing something like this: `int zero = 0; Node* head = zero;` but that is not the case in the code shown (`Node *head = 0;` would work fine, though).

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 reports an error:   cannot convert from 'Node *'  to  'int *'  . The question doesn't show LinkedList.h, which could somehow be causing the problem. For example, if LinkedList.h defines NODE_H_, then node.h is not being used.

Answer (score 3):

`Node* head;` is just a declaration of an uninitialized pointer, it can't throw a conversion error.

`int whyDoesThisWork = new Node();` will fail to compile, because a pointer cannot be assigned to an `int` (without an explicit type-cast). This is a type mismatch.  Are you sure the compiler is not actually saying `error: invalid conversion from 'Node*' to 'int'` instead?

`int* val = new Node();` will also fail to compile, because a `Node*` pointer is not an `int*` pointer.  This is also a type mismatch.

C++ is a strongly typed language.  It is not forgiving of type mismatches, unless *implicit conversions* are defined for the types in question, which is not the case here.

Comment: Does gcc cache files or have strange errors randomly? I thought it has been in use for decades and that errors like this would be ironed out. I did not edit or save my code since a fresh rebuild so either GCC is buggy or my old computer is making too many computers

Comment: @ErikAwwad experience has taught me that when I'm convinced I've found a compiler bug I must redouble my efforts to find my bug, because it's *never* the compiler's fault.  Especially one as widely used and tested as `gcc`.

Comment: @ErikAwwad The likelihood that you've found a compiler bug with the code you show is about as much as you having won USD 500 million in lotto. Give or take an order magnitude. Try compiling your code on e.g. http://godbolt.org, since that's a known good platform. I can assure you there's no compiler bug involved. You're doing something wrong, that's all.

Comment: @ErikAwwad Compiler bugs are usually found in code so esoteric, very few programmers would ever encounter it.   Your code is straightforward, simple, C++.  If a compiler vendor could not handle that code, they would be laughed out of the business.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica it compiles completely fine through various online c++ compilers

Comment: @ErikAwwad Awesome. Then there's no problem with your code nor with the compilers. You're doing something wrong on your own system. You're not explaining how you compile your code, so it's impossible to say what it is that you're doing wrong. But certainly it's a problem on your end. If you actually want help, instead of just complaining that no help is forthcoming - you must show exactly what you do, starting from a clean build folder. Do a screen recording if you must, but there's no other way - we need to see your hands, so to speak.